# Cannot open Java Preferences

Tags: macbook-pro, snow-leopard, java

I don't know what the problem is. I recently went to Lion (Developer Preview) and restored a fresh new copy of 10.6. I later updated everything and then tried to open Java. It keeps giving me this error.

```
Cannot open Java Preferences 10.6
No compatible version of Java 1.5+ is available
```

I've tried reinstalling the update, but it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

:P, solved it. I just plugged my 10.6 restore disk in and ran the setup. I then updated the software, and voila, I fixed it.

Answer (score -1):

Launch the preference panel with this terminal command:

```
javaws -viewer
```